# How to remove padding from Flutter built-in stepper widget

Tags: flutter, padding, uistepper

I want to remove the padding of Flutter's stepper widget in order to create control buttons that don't have any space between them and the horizontal edges of the screen.

What I've tried:

- I've found [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62640147/how-can-i-remove-space-around-the-card-in-flutter), where the answer says the only
  way to do that would be to create my own version of the stepper
  widget, but I did not understand what that person meant by that: should I try
  to create from scratch a copy of the built-in widget and adjust it to
  fit my needs? It seems like too much time and effort only to change a
  small detail like this.
- Also, I tried to modify the padding of the built-in
  stepper widget (stepper.dart), navigating to it's source code and,
  inside the _buildHorizontal() function, changing the value of the
  padding property from EdgeInsets.all(24) to EdgeInsets.all(0). It
  worked, but would it be a good idea to do this? Modify a bundled
  flutter widget?
- Furthermore, I've managed to bypass this padding restriction
  surrounding the buttons with the "UnconstrainedBox" widget. The only
  problem is that, as expected, the child (buttons) overflow it's
  parent (the stepper), causing those overflow stripes to be shown
  during development. Would it be bad if I left this overflow happen?

Here's my code where the problem appears:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TestStepperScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const TestStepperScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _TestStepperScreenState createState() => _TestStepperScreenState();
}

class _TestStepperScreenState extends State<TestStepperScreen> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: IconButton(
          onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios_new),
        ),
        title: Text(
          'Test stepper',
        ),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Stepper(
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(0),
          type: StepperType.horizontal,
          controlsBuilder: (BuildContext context, ControlsDetails details) {
            return Container(
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: null,
                      child: Text('Cancel'),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: null,
                      child: Text('Continue'),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            );
          },
          steps: [
            Step(
              title: SizedBox(),
              content: Column(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    child: Text('test'),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Step(
              title: SizedBox(),
              content: Column(
                children: [
                  Container(),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Step(
              title: SizedBox(),
              content: Column(
                children: [
                  Container(),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And here's my code using the UnconstrainedBox (desired behaviour):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TestStepperScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const TestStepperScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _TestStepperScreenState createState() => _TestStepperScreenState();
}

class _TestStepperScreenState extends State<TestStepperScreen> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: IconButton(
          onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios_new),
        ),
        title: Text(
          'Test stepper',
        ),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Stepper(
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(0),
          type: StepperType.horizontal,
          controlsBuilder: (BuildContext context, ControlsDetails details) {
            return UnconstrainedBox(
              child: Container(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      child: ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: null,
                        child: Text('Cancel'),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: null,
                        child: Text('Continue'),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
          steps: [
            Step(
              title: SizedBox(),
              content: Column(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    child: Text('test'),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Step(
              title: SizedBox(),
              content: Column(
                children: [
                  Container(),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Step(
              title: SizedBox(),
              content: Column(
                children: [
                  Container(),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Any kind of help would be highly appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

you can customize the whole stepper widget to delete the padding, follow these steps:

1. create dart file called custom_stepper for example
2. put the code at the bottom here in this file(note that it's very big code)
3. use the CustomStepper widget not Stepper

the result, the next image with Stepper:

[image]

the next image with CustomStepper:

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

typedef ControlsWidgetBuilder = Widget Function(
    BuildContext context, ControlsDetails details);

const TextStyle _kStepStyle = TextStyle(
  fontSize: 12.0,
  color: Colors.white,
);
const Color _kErrorLight = Colors.red;
final Color _kErrorDark = Colors.red.shade400;
const Color _kCircleActiveLight = Colors.white;
const Color _kCircleActiveDark = Colors.black87;
const Color _kDisabledLight = Colors.black38;
const Color _kDisabledDark = Colors.white38;
const double _kStepSize = 24.0;
const double _kTriangleHeight =
    _kStepSize * 0.866025;

class CustomStepper extends StatefulWidget {


  const CustomStepper({
    Key? key,
    required this.steps,
    this.physics,
    this.type = StepperType.vertical,
    this.currentStep = 0,
    this.onStepTapped,
    this.onStepContinue,
    this.onStepCancel,
    this.controlsBuilder,
    this.elevation,
    this.margin,
  })
      : assert(steps != null),
        assert(type != null),
        assert(currentStep != null),
        assert(0 <= currentStep && currentStep < steps.length),
        super(key: key);


  final List<Step> steps;


  final ScrollPhysics? physics;


  final StepperType type;


  final int currentStep;


  final ValueChanged<int>? onStepTapped;


  final VoidCallback? onStepContinue;


  final VoidCallback? onStepCancel;


  final ControlsWidgetBuilder? controlsBuilder;


  final double? elevation;


  final EdgeInsetsGeometry? margin;

  @override
  State<CustomStepper> createState() => _CustomStepperState();
}

class _CustomStepperState extends State<CustomStepper>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  late List<GlobalKey> _keys;
  final Map<int, StepState> _oldStates = <int, StepState>{};

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _keys = List<GlobalKey>.generate(
      widget.steps.length,
          (int i) => GlobalKey(),
    );

    for (int i = 0; i < widget.steps.length; i += 1)
      _oldStates[i] = widget.steps[i].state;
  }

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(CustomStepper oldWidget) {
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
    assert(widget.steps.length == oldWidget.steps.length);

    for (int i = 0; i < oldWidget.steps.length; i += 1)
      _oldStates[i] = oldWidget.steps[i].state;
  }

  bool _isFirst(int index) {
    return index == 0;
  }

  bool _isLast(int index) {
    return widget.steps.length - 1 == index;
  }

  bool _isCurrent(int index) {
    return widget.currentStep == index;
  }

  bool _isDark() {
    return Theme
        .of(context)
        .brightness == Brightness.dark;
  }

  Widget _buildLine(bool visible) {
    return Container(
      width: visible ? 1.0 : 0.0,
      height: 16.0,
      color: Colors.grey.shade400,
    );
  }

  Widget _buildCircleChild(int index, bool oldState) {
    final StepState state =
    oldState ? _oldStates[index]! : widget.steps[index].state;
    final bool isDarkActive = _isDark() && widget.steps[index].isActive;
    assert(state != null);
    switch (state) {
      case StepState.indexed:
      case StepState.disabled:
        return Text(
          '${index + 1}',
          style: isDarkActive
              ? _kStepStyle.copyWith(color: Colors.black87)
              : _kStepStyle,
        );
      case StepState.editing:
        return Icon(
          Icons.edit,
          color: isDarkActive ? _kCircleActiveDark : _kCircleActiveLight,
          size: 18.0,
        );
      case StepState.complete:
        return Icon(
          Icons.check,
          color: isDarkActive ? _kCircleActiveDark : _kCircleActiveLight,
          size: 18.0,
        );
      case StepState.error:
        return const Text('!', style: _kStepStyle);
    }
  }

  Color _circleColor(int index) {
    final ColorScheme colorScheme = Theme
        .of(context)
        .colorScheme;
    if (!_isDark()) {
      return widget.steps[index].isActive
          ? colorScheme.primary
          : colorScheme.onSurface.withOpacity(0.38);
    } else {
      return widget.steps[index].isActive
          ? colorScheme.secondary
          : colorScheme.background;
    }
  }

  Widget _buildCircle(int index, bool oldState) {
    return Container(

      width: _kStepSize,
      height: _kStepSize,
      child: AnimatedContainer(
        curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
        duration: kThemeAnimationDuration,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: _circleColor(index),
          shape: BoxShape.circle,
        ),
        child: Center(
          child: _buildCircleChild(
              index, oldState && widget.steps[index].state == StepState.error),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildTriangle(int index, bool oldState) {
    return Container(

      width: _kStepSize,
      height: _kStepSize,
      child: Center(
        child: SizedBox(
          width: _kStepSize,
          height:
          _kTriangleHeight,
          child: CustomPaint(
            painter: _TrianglePainter(
              color: _isDark() ? _kErrorDark : _kErrorLight,
            ),
            child: Align(
              alignment: const Alignment(
                  0.0, 0.8),
              child: _buildCircleChild(index,
                  oldState && widget.steps[index].state != StepState.error),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildIcon(int index) {
    if (widget.steps[index].state != _oldStates[index]) {
      return AnimatedCrossFade(
        firstChild: _buildCircle(index, true),
        secondChild: _buildTriangle(index, true),
        firstCurve: const Interval(0.0, 0.6, curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn),
        secondCurve: const Interval(0.4, 1.0, curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn),
        sizeCurve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
        crossFadeState: widget.steps[index].state == StepState.error
            ? CrossFadeState.showSecond
            : CrossFadeState.showFirst,
        duration: kThemeAnimationDuration,
      );
    } else {
      if (widget.steps[index].state != StepState.error)
        return _buildCircle(index, false);
      else
        return _buildTriangle(index, false);
    }
  }

  Widget _buildVerticalControls(int stepIndex) {
    if (widget.controlsBuilder != null)
      return widget.controlsBuilder!(
        context,
        ControlsDetails(
          currentStep: widget.currentStep,
          onStepContinue: widget.onStepContinue,
          onStepCancel: widget.onStepCancel,
          stepIndex: stepIndex,
        ),
      );

    final Color cancelColor;
    switch (Theme
        .of(context)
        .brightness) {
      case Brightness.light:
        cancelColor = Colors.black54;
        break;
      case Brightness.dark:
        cancelColor = Colors.white70;
        break;
    }

    final ThemeData themeData = Theme.of(context);
    final ColorScheme colorScheme = themeData.colorScheme;
    final MaterialLocalizations localizations =
    MaterialLocalizations.of(context);

    const OutlinedBorder buttonShape = RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(2)));
    const EdgeInsets buttonPadding = EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0);

    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16.0),
      child: ConstrainedBox(
        constraints: const BoxConstraints.tightFor(height: 48.0),
        child: Row(


          children: <Widget>[
            TextButton(
              onPressed: widget.onStepContinue,
              style: ButtonStyle(
                foregroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Color?>(
                        (Set<MaterialState> states) {
                      return states.contains(MaterialState.disabled)
                          ? null
                          : (_isDark()
                          ? colorScheme.onSurface
                          : colorScheme.onPrimary);
                    }),
                backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Color?>(
                        (Set<MaterialState> states) {
                      return _isDark() ||
                          states.contains(MaterialState.disabled)
                          ? null
                          : colorScheme.primary;
                    }),
                padding: MaterialStateProperty.all<EdgeInsetsGeometry>(
                    buttonPadding),
                shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<OutlinedBorder>(buttonShape),
              ),
              child: Text(localizations.continueButtonLabel),
            ),
            Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(start: 8.0),
              child: TextButton(
                onPressed: widget.onStepCancel,
                style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                  primary: cancelColor,
                  padding: buttonPadding,
                  shape: buttonShape,
                ),
                child: Text(localizations.cancelButtonLabel),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  TextStyle _titleStyle(int index) {
    final ThemeData themeData = Theme.of(context);
    final TextTheme textTheme = themeData.textTheme;

    assert(widget.steps[index].state != null);
    switch (widget.steps[index].state) {
      case StepState.indexed:
      case StepState.editing:
      case StepState.complete:
        return textTheme.bodyText1!;
      case StepState.disabled:
        return textTheme.bodyText1!.copyWith(
          color: _isDark() ? _kDisabledDark : _kDisabledLight,
        );
      case StepState.error:
        return textTheme.bodyText1!.copyWith(
          color: _isDark() ? _kErrorDark : _kErrorLight,
        );
    }
  }

  TextStyle _subtitleStyle(int index) {
    final ThemeData themeData = Theme.of(context);
    final TextTheme textTheme = themeData.textTheme;

    assert(widget.steps[index].state != null);
    switch (widget.steps[index].state) {
      case StepState.indexed:
      case StepState.editing:
      case StepState.complete:
        return textTheme.caption!;
      case StepState.disabled:
        return textTheme.caption!.copyWith(
          color: _isDark() ? _kDisabledDark : _kDisabledLight,
        );
      case StepState.error:
        return textTheme.caption!.copyWith(
          color: _isDark() ? _kErrorDark : _kErrorLight,
        );
    }
  }

  Widget _buildHeaderText(int index) {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: <Widget>[
        AnimatedDefaultTextStyle(
          style: _titleStyle(index),
          duration: kThemeAnimationDuration,
          curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
          child: widget.steps[index].title,
        ),
        if (widget.steps[index].subtitle != null)
          Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 2.0),
            child: AnimatedDefaultTextStyle(
              style: _subtitleStyle(index),
              duration: kThemeAnimationDuration,
              curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
              child: widget.steps[index].subtitle!,
            ),
          ),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _buildVerticalHeader(int index) {
    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24.0),
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Column(
            children: <Widget>[


              _buildLine(!_isFirst(index)),
              _buildIcon(index),
              _buildLine(!_isLast(index)),
            ],
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(start: 12.0),
              child: _buildHeaderText(index),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildVerticalBody(int index) {
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        PositionedDirectional(
          start: 24.0,
          top: 0.0,
          bottom: 0.0,
          child: SizedBox(
            width: 24.0,
            child: Center(
              child: SizedBox(
                width: _isLast(index) ? 0.0 : 1.0,
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.grey.shade400,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        AnimatedCrossFade(
          firstChild: Container(height: 0.0),
          secondChild: Container(
            margin: widget.margin ??
                const EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(
                  start: 60.0,
                  end: 24.0,

                ),
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                widget.steps[index].content,
                _buildVerticalControls(index),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          firstCurve: const Interval(0.0, 0.6, curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn),
          secondCurve: const Interval(0.4, 1.0, curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn),
          sizeCurve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
          crossFadeState: _isCurrent(index)
              ? CrossFadeState.showSecond
              : CrossFadeState.showFirst,
          duration: kThemeAnimationDuration,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _buildVertical() {
    return ListView(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      physics: widget.physics,
      children: <Widget>[
        for (int i = 0; i < widget.steps.length; i += 1)
          Column(
            key: _keys[i],
            children: <Widget>[
              InkWell(
                onTap: widget.steps[i].state != StepState.disabled
                    ? () {
                  Scrollable.ensureVisible(
                    _keys[i].currentContext!,
                    curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
                    duration: kThemeAnimationDuration,
                  );

                  widget.onStepTapped?.call(i);
                }
                    : null,
                canRequestFocus: widget.steps[i].state != StepState.disabled,
                child: _buildVerticalHeader(i),
              ),
              _buildVerticalBody(i),
            ],
          ),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _buildHorizontal() {
    final List<Widget> children = <Widget>[
      for (int i = 0; i < widget.steps.length; i += 1) ...<Widget>[
        InkResponse(
          onTap: widget.steps[i].state != StepState.disabled
              ? () {
            widget.onStepTapped?.call(i);
          }
              : null,
          canRequestFocus: widget.steps[i].state != StepState.disabled,
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              SizedBox(
                height: 72.0,
                child: Center(
                  child: _buildIcon(i),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(start: 12.0),
                child: _buildHeaderText(i),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        if (!_isLast(i))
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
              height: 1.0,
              color: Colors.grey.shade400,
            ),
          ),
      ],
    ];

    final List<Widget> stepPanels = <Widget>[];
    for (int i = 0; i < widget.steps.length; i += 1) {
      stepPanels.add(
        Visibility(
          maintainState: true,
          visible: i == widget.currentStep,
          child: widget.steps[i].content,
        ),
      );
    }

    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Material(
          elevation: widget.elevation ?? 2,
          child: Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24.0),
            child: Row(
              children: children,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: ListView(
            physics: widget.physics,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24.0),
            children: <Widget>[
              AnimatedSize(
                curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
                duration: kThemeAnimationDuration,
                child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                    children: stepPanels),
              ),
              _buildVerticalControls(widget.currentStep),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    assert(debugCheckHasMaterial(context));
    assert(debugCheckHasMaterialLocalizations(context));
    assert(() {
      if (context.findAncestorWidgetOfExactType<CustomStepper>() != null)
        throw FlutterError(
            'Steppers must not be nested.\n'
                'The material specification advises that one should avoid embedding '
                'steppers within steppers. '
                'https:
        );
      return true;
    }());
    assert(widget.type != null);
    switch (widget.type) {
      case StepperType.vertical:
        return _buildVertical();
      case StepperType.horizontal:
        return _buildHorizontal();
    }
  }
}


class _TrianglePainter extends CustomPainter {
  _TrianglePainter({
    required this.color,
  });

  final Color color;

  @override
  bool hitTest(Offset point) => true;

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(_TrianglePainter oldPainter) {
    return oldPainter.color != color;
  }

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final double base = size.width;
    final double halfBase = size.width / 2.0;
    final double height = size.height;
    final List<Offset> points = <Offset>[
      Offset(0.0, height),
      Offset(base, height),
      Offset(halfBase, 0.0),
    ];

    canvas.drawPath(
      Path()
        ..addPolygon(points, true),
      Paint()
        ..color = color,
    );
  }
}
```